# CSS Full body width background aligned to floated items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a full width background or image behind floated items within a max-width container. The page will be responsive so I can't fix the height of the .item objects nor be sure how many will be shown on each row.

I'd like to have a background or image running full length of the window aligned to a position in the .item div. I can use a very long div or image offset to the left without any issue but the right side makes the browser scroll which I don't want.

```
.bg {
      background: red;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 30px;
      left: -1000px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 2000px;
      z-index: 0;
}
```

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/K8uAh/4/

The red banner is my background, see how it runs off to the right.

Ideally I would do this just using CSS, I know if I have to go the JavaScript route it all gets a bit clunky on the window resize.

Comment: 1. You're right to stay with CSS and not get involved with JS. 2. it won't get _a bit clunky_ if you would wrap all the JS code with a function and add this function as an event handler for `window.onresize`. It's that simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.container`. If you don't want the container to extend the entire width you need to remove `overflow: hidden;` and add it to an additional wrapper div.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I needed, add a new wrapper with width 100% and overflow hidden, take overflow hidden off my container div which is required to limit the width of the content.  http://jsfiddle.net/K8uAh/5/  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I tried on your fiddle and altered the width and the left attribute to have percentage instead of px as if we are dealing with px then it will be hard to make it responsive.

Code:

```
 .bg {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125%;
    left:-16%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/K8uAh/1/

Comment: I have updated my fiddle, there was a stray bracket I hadn't spotted.  I am looking for the background to run across the whole body, beyond the container that holds the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `clear-fix` div at the end of `.item`.

```
body {
    width: 100%
}

.container{
    background: red; /* Change your color here */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item{
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YmbjV/5/)

Answer (score 0):

**First** : your fiddle css is incorrect :

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
} /*<- extra closing braces here is ruining your layout*/
```

[see what i mean](http://jsfiddle.net/K8uAh/2/)

**second** : to have a full width bg use:

```
 background: #ccc url('http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Flower-Vintage-Background-640x400.jpg');
 background-size :100% 100%;
```

`container` class should be :

```
.container {
    background: #ccc url('http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Flower-Vintage-Background-640x400.jpg');
    background-size :100% 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8uAh/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I spotted that after I got to work and have updated the fiddle.  I need the background/image to extend the entire body width, not just the container.